# "Cannot be resolved to a type" in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am very new in trying to learn to code in java.

I have done some tutorials and exercises from English speakers, but if I try to use code from my native language (Danish) programming books, I get a lot of errors in eclipse. They mostly consist of "cannot be resolved to a variable/type".

E.g. in the following code, the first errors I get is

> spillere cannot be resolved or is not a field

and

> Spiller cannot be resolved to a type

Is there something missing I need to declare?
Hope this is enough information for any help :)

```
public class Matadorspil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matadorspil spil = new Matadorspil();
        spil.spillere.add(new Spiller("Søren", 50000));
        spil.spillere.add(new Spiller("Gitte", 50000));

        for (spil.spillersTur = 0; spil.spillersTur < 40; spil.spillersTur++) {
            Spiller sp = spil.spillere.get(spil.spillersTur % spil.spillere.size());
        }
        int slag = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        System.out.println("***** " + sp.navn + " på felt " + sp.feltnr + " slår " + slag);

        for (int i = 1; i <= slag; i = i + 1) {
            sp.feltnr = sp.feltnr + 1;
        }

        if (sp.feltnr == spil.felter.size()) {
            sp.feltnr = 0;
        }

        Felt felt = spil.felter.get(sp.feltnr);

        if (i < slag) {
            felt.passeret(sp);
        } else {
            felt.landet(sp);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Matadorspil only have a static main method. It doesn't have any field. So it doesn't have a field `spillere`.

Answer (score 2):

That hasn't to do with your language. When you do `spil.spillere`, you must have this field (`spillere`) in the class Matadorspil. That's why you got the first error. For the second error, you must either create a class named `Spiller` or import the class from its package. Maybe, you didn't copy the code entirely. Come back to the place where you learned, and check it out.